# Error when awk command's parameter is being used in pattern

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I'm running these commands:

```
ps -ef | awk -v piddd="$child_pid" '$2 ~ /\<piddd\>/ { print $3; }'
ps -ef | awk -v piddd="$child_pid" '$2 ~ /piddd/ { print $3; }'
```

It doesn't give me any result. When I try with this one, I get what I need, although in some cases I'll get additional pids:

```
ps -ef | awk -v piddd="$child_pid" '$2 ~ piddd { print $3; }'
```

What is wrong with first ones?

Comment: It looks like you want to print the `PPID` of a known `$child_pid`. You don't need to reinvent the wheels, you can simply run `ps -o ppid= -p $child_pid`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a variable with the `/pattern/` syntax.

If you want to add word boundaries (and your version of awk supports the syntax), you can do so by concatenating strings:

```
ps -ef | awk -v piddd="$child_pid" '$2 ~ "\\<" piddd "\\>" { print $3 }'
```

Note that the `\` must be escaped in this case.

If you just want the whole field to match the exact variable, I'd suggest using a simple string comparison:

```
ps -ef | awk -v piddd="$child_pid" '$2 == piddd { print $3 }'
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a need to parse the output of `ps` utility just to get the parent pid `PPID` of a child `PID`. The `ps` utility already provides this functionality.

`ps -o ppid= -p $child_pid`

The parameter `-o ppid=` tells `ps` to just print the parent pid. Without `=` the printout will contain a header `PPID`.

The parameter `-p $child_pid` tells `ps` to get the process information from the process id identified by variable `$child_pid`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ps -ef | awk '$2 ~ /'`echo "$child_pid"`'/ { print $3; }'

# or

ps -ef | awk '$2 ~ /'$child_pid'/ { print $3; }'

# or create function
function father_pid() { ps -ef | awk '$2 ~ /'$1'/ { print $3; }'; }

# use function
father_pid $child_pid
```